# CSS Float for a navbar

Tags: css, css-float

Playing around with float and I faced an issue I can't get my head around. Consider the following code for making a simple nav ([Navbar with no floating children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm20h.png)).

```
    <div style="background-color: rgb(65, 224, 185); padding: 2% 15%;">
      <span class="navbar-item">Best City Guide</span>
      <span class="navbar-item">Best City Guide</span>
      <span class="navbar-item">ICE CREAM</span>
      <span class="navbar-item">DONUTS</span>
      <span class="navbar-item">TEA</span>
      <span class="navbar-item">COFFEE</span>
    </div>
```

Now if I use float right on the last three spans, they will float to the right, nonetheless, they will not stay on the same line as the spans on the left as shown in: [Navbar with floating children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV7Dl.png).

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: what output you want exactly ?

Comment: provide your css code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```css
nav{
  background-color: rgb(65, 224, 185);
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
nav span{
  padding: 8px;
  margin:5px;
}
.navbar-item{
  background: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
}
span.navbar-item:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span class="navbar-item">Best City Guide</span>
  <span class="navbar-item">Best City Guide</span>
  <span class="navbar-item">ICE CREAM</span>
  <span class="navbar-item">DONUTS</span>
  <span class="navbar-item">TEA</span>
  <span class="navbar-item">COFFEE</span>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi your question isn't understandable. But I'll give my solution.

I recommend you to use **css flex**. With `justify-content: space-between;`

Find code here for flex - https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-goay7v

If you want to stick with float go ahead, But you need to change your DOM structure. Wrap whatever you want to float in a div and apply float to it(the wrapper element). In that case both will remain in same line and also you wont loose the order of the elements.

Find code here for float - https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rmcsxn